# getting error while inserting data in the database using ef core , No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

I'm inserting data into the database in .net core with if core I'm able to get the data from the get API, but while I'm inserting the data into the database getting error. And its a compilation error at Context.

Error
InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext. On Configuring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Context class

```
 public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Mplus> MpData { get; set; }

    }
```

APIController

```
namespace MplusApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MPlusController : ControllerBase
    {

        private Context _context;

        public MPlusController(Context context) {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("{Ftemp}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int Ftemp) {

            using (var context = new Context())//Getting compilation error here
            {
                var mp = new Mplus()
                {
                    Ftemp = Ftemp,

                };
                context.MpData.Add(mp);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return Ok();
        }

    }
```

Model

```
 public class Mplus
    {

        public int Ftemp { get; set; }
    }
```

startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }


        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell EF which provider to use (SQL Server, SQLite, etc). You have two options. Either do that when registering the DbContext on Startup class' ConfigureServices method, as in:

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(@"connection string"));
```

Or doing that in the DbContext-derived class, on the OnConfiguring method:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    builder.UseSqlServer(@"connection string");
```

}

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.

Also, you need to use the Context instance you are injecting, not build a new Context object - if you would do that, you would need to pass an DbContextOptions instance, as you do not have a public parameterless constructor.

Something like this:

```
var mp = new Mplus()
{
    Ftemp = Ftemp,
};
_context.MpData.Add(mp);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: which file i need to write . startup.cs?

Comment: Yes, ConfigureServices method.

Comment: i have already written that. can u check my post i have updated.

Comment: You need to use the injected constructor, _context, not build a new one. See my updated answer.

Comment: but what argument i need to pass here,   using (var context = new Context())

Comment: Come on, this is a very basic question... you must use _context, not create a new instance (remove the using block).

Comment: thanks its working . i just removed using block and used _context.